# Apache2, Crowd OpenID SSO Authentication with Directory based LDAP issue with Git/Gerrit

Tags: git, apache, ubuntu, authentication

This question involves apache2, Crowd OpenID SSO authentication with Delegated

Directory based LDAP issue with Git/Gerrit.

**My Environment details:**

```
* Operating system: Ubuntu 12.4 LTS – 64 bit.
* Apache2 Version: Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
* Server built:   Mar  5 2015 18:10:14
* Crowd Version - Atlassian Crowd Version: 2.8.2
```

**Problem description:**

I have configured Crowd OpenID SSO authentication with Delegated directory
type Microsoft Active Directory with our LDAP settings and provided necessary permissions to crowd-openid-server settings and to our git/gerrit server.

Currently my (gerrit.config) file has below settings to access our git/gerrit portal.

```
[auth]
type = OPENID_SSO
openIdSsoUrl = http://100.101.102.103:8095/openidserver/
logoutUrl = http:// 100.101.102.103:8095/gerrit_logout.html
```

But when tried access my gerrit portal, front end shows the sign in button.  Once I clicked that the authentication not forwarding to crowd page to enter my login-id and password. It remains on local host itself (meaning remains on gerrit portal itself).

Note: we have two servers: one for Git/Gerrit & another one for Crowd.

So kindly advise me to fix the same.

Comment: Gerrit Log shows following msg,                                                       [2015-05-29 12:30:01,605] ERROR com.google.gerrit.httpd.auth.openid.OpenIdServiceImpl : Cannot discover OpenID http://100.101.102.103:8095/openidserver/op
org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisException: 0x706: GET failed on http://100.101.102.103:8095/openidserver/op : 404

Comment: Is there any plugin available to authenticate gerrit through crowd?